# Identifying whether a list item is in a string

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a nested loop sequence which looks through a series of stopwords and a list of strings and identifies whether or not each stopword is in each list item. Ideally, I'd like to be able to add the words that are present in each string to a new column and remove them all from the string.

Does anyone have tips? Are my loops in the wrong order?

```
def remove_stops(text, customStops):
    """
    Removes custom stopwords.

    Parameters
    ----------
    text : the variable storing strings from which
        stopwords should be removed. This can be a string
        or a pandas DataFrame.
    customStops : the list of stopwords which should be removed. 

    Returns
    -------
    Cleansed lists.

    """
    for item in text:
        print("Text:", item)
        for word in customStops:
            print("Custom Stops: ", word)
            if word in item:
                print("Word: ", word)
                #Add word to list of words in item
                #Remove word from item
```

Comment: If you provide some test input as well as the call to the remove_stops() function, I'm sure there are people (like me ;-) who can assist you. What do you mean by 'move to a new column'?

Comment: @Ronald Thanks for adding this request, this was my first post on SO :) I'll make sure to do that in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
def remove_stops(text, customStops):
    found = {k:[] for k in text} # Dict for all found stopwords in text
    for i,item in enumerate(text):
        for word in customStops:
            text[i] = text[i].replace(word,'') # Remove all stopwords from each string, if the stopword is not in, the replace will just leave it as it is
            if word in item:
                found[item].append(word)
    return text, found

text = ['Today is my lucky day!',
        'Tomorrow is rainy',
        'Please help!',
        'I want to fly']

customStops = ['help', 'fly']

clean, found = remove_stops(text, customStops)

print(clean)
print(found)
```

Output:

```
['Today is my lucky day!',
 'Tomorrow is rainy',
 'Please !',
 'I want to ']


{'Today is my lucky day!': [],
 'Tomorrow is rainy': [],
 'Please help!': ['help'],
 'I want to fly': ['fly']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ann!

Comment: Did you get what you're looking for?

Comment: I have one clarifying question - is the reason for converting the two lists to a dictionary just to make the iteration faster, or to make sure that the stopwords are matched up correctly with the initial texts?

Comment: When I try to run this, I get the error "unhashable type: 'list'", because it attempts to create a dictionary key from list values. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: @codedindc No, the error is when we attempt to make `list`s into dictionary keys. The string *values* from the `list` *are* hashable. Please post a separate question if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Ann! I was apparently trying to create keys using a list of lists, which wasn't possible, so I flattened the list and converted to strings.